# Adding item to specific tableview section in a 'Routine' tab. Each day holds it's own list or routines

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

My goal is to have a concise data structure that has a key that corresponds to each day of the week, in each day there are a list of tasks that can go into 1 of 3 sections in the tableview. Here is my code below.

```
struct Routines {
    let thumbnailImg: String
    let routineName: String
    let duration: String
}

struct RoutineTask {
    var taskSection: String
    var task: Routines
}

// routineList will contain all 7 days of week, with a value of RoutineTask which tracks the section that task belongs to and the task itself
var routinesList: [String: RoutineTask?] = [
    "Monday" : nil,
    "Tuesday" : nil,
    "Wednesday" : nil,
    "Thursday" : nil,
    "Friday" : nil,
    "Saturday" : nil,
    "Sunday" : nil
]

let routine = RoutineTask(taskSection: "WarmUp", task: Routines(thumbnailImg: "Crunches", routineName: "Sit ups", duration: "75 secs"))
routinesList["Monday"] = routine
```

Above is my code for how I'm approaching this problem, but I feel it could be made better. Am I overcomplicating this or does my code look funny? I'm just seeking advice on how to better this code. I'll attach photo of the app so you can have a visual for how the code works.

Photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqOAS.jpg

The routine tab has a tableview which holds 3 sections, "Warm-up", "Workout" and "Stretches". When the user creates a new routine task, they specify which section it will go to. The way I think of the problem is to have dictionary whose key corresponds to a day of the week and it's value is of type 'RoutineTask', RoutineTasks is a struct which will keep track of the tableview sections with 'taskSection' property and hold Routines in the 'task' property.

So now that you guys have a general idea of my code, do you think this is the right approach? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm doing? Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using more `enums` would be a better idea. Having your app's data be strongly typed and the ability to use `switch` statements is much nicer than having to compare strings everywhere. For instance, instead of using `"Monday"`, `"Tuesday"`, etc. you can declare an `enum`, and even still get the name of the day right from the `enum` with `monday.rawValue`.

```
enum Weekday : String {
    case monday = "Monday"
    case tuesday = "Tuesday"
    // ...
}
```

Even more `enums` for `taskSection` and `routineName` would be great as well. The following `enum` can be used to give a `RoutineName` an even more specific name.

```
enum RoutineName {
    case crunches(name: String)
}
```